# Remove third column without removing header

Tags: shell, awk

I wanted to remove third column from csv file,

```
input.csv 
col1|col2|col3|col4 
aaa1|aaa2|aaa|aaa3|aaa4 
bbb1|bbb2|bbb|bbb3|bbb4 
ccc1|ccc2|ccc|ccc3|ccc4
```

I just want to remove the contents from the third column and without removing the header.

```
output.csv 
col1|col2|col3|col4 
aaa1|aaa2|aaa3|aaa4 
bbb1|bbb2|bbb3|bbb4 
ccc1|ccc2|ccc3|ccc4
```

I have tried below solution, but it is not working.

`awk 'BEGIN{FS="\t";OFS="\t"}NR==1{print}NR>1{$1=""; print substr($0,2)}' input.csv > output.csv`

Comment: What's your field separator? tab or pipe?

Comment: why are you clearing the 1st column (`$1`) instead of the third column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like this

```
sed '1!s/[^|]*|//3' input.csv >output.csv
```

in case of one file, it can be done inplace

```
sed -i '1!s/[^|]*|//3' file.csv
```

Answer (score 1):

With **GNU** awk and `|` as field separator:

```
awk 'BEGIN{ FS=OFS="|" } NR>1{ $3=$4; $4=$5; NF-- }1' file.csv
```

Output:

```
col1|col2|col3|col4 
aaa1|aaa2|aaa3|aaa4 
bbb1|bbb2|bbb3|bbb4 
ccc1|ccc2|ccc3|ccc4
```

---

See: [8 Powerful Awk Built-in Variables – FS, OFS, RS, ORS, NR, NF, FILENAME, FNR](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/01/8-powerful-awk-built-in-variables-fs-ofs-rs-ors-nr-nf-filename-fnr/)